# Testing `$window.addEventListener`

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

Inside a service I have the following code

```
 $window.addEventListener('eventName', eventNameFunction);
```

I am using chai to do all of my testing. My problem is that I can not trigger an event to test the listener. It seems like phantomJS does not have anything I can use on `$document` or `$window` to trigger events.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and found a solution?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Sadly not, I look back every now and then but am still stumped by it